# How to add a view for a node with an ID?

Tags: views, nodes

I have a simple blog application and would like to add style my nodes with views. More specifically I want to style node/nid path and when I point that in the views configuration, it only works if I type: http://example.com/node/3/3 
but if I type http://example.com/node/3 it doesn't work. How can I make the nodes view work with the id being pointed out only once?

If my frontpage is called /content then that would be the path I would point out in the views configuration. In this case, however, I am trying to style an opened node - t.i. where the path is node/id . Everything works fine if I type `node/id/id` in the adress bar, but not if I type `node/id` . As the path for that view I have done so: PAGE SETTINGS `Path:/node/%`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're doing so far. Can you [skitch](http://evernote.com/skitch/) a screenshot of your Views configuration, and describe in more detail the steps you took so far?

Comment: You can edit the question to add information in a way that is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd find [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) with a node_view panel page override suits there.

Install and enable page manager then enable the default "Node view" panel page.

It will override node/%node with a page in which you can embed views content pane displays etc...

Comment: Thanks, I found http://jamestombs.co.uk/2011-08-18/use-panels-override-node-output-drupal-7 this and it did the job!